# Finding DNS settings of a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, user-accounts

My client has DNS for their domain name hosted with a DNS host separate to their domain registrar.

The person who setup the account with the DNS Host hasn't been contactable for over 2 years. This hasn't been a problem, until now. My client needs settings added to their DNS.

I could move the DNS Hosting back to the Domain Registrar, but I'm worried of breaking something given I don't know exactly how it's configured, given nobody has access to the account with the DNS Host (any they understandably refuse to provide the details).

Is there a way I can find the DNS configuration of the domain with all the associated A records, MX records etc, so I know what to set it all to if I move the DNS Hosting back to the Domain Registrar?

Comment: Is your client the named Administrative Contact for the domain? Are you the named Technical Contact for the domain? If so you can request the information from the registrar/DNS host based on that. They certainly won't give you access to someone else's account, but they should be willing to provide you with a zone dump. (And if you're not the named contacts you have another problem to deal with now...)

Comment: @voretaq7 this is the most logical and simple approach.  Good suggestion. Can this be eligible as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the rights to see the information, you can't see them ! You can check if the zone transfert is allowed (named AXFR) then you will receive all the zone but if it is not the case, you must have access to the zone file in the DNS manager of your domain registrar.

To take the zone with AXFR, you can use `host -t AXFR <zone>.` Don't forget the dot at the end !

Answer (score 0):

As Dom said, if Zone transfer is permitted, you can access the entire Zone information by querying for AXFR record like `dig AXFR domain.tld [@nameserver]`

Any of the following commands will give you the NS, MX and other records of `domain.tld` but not its sub domains (for eg. sub1.domain.tld)

```
dig ANY domain.tld
host -a domain.tld
nslookup -type=any domain.tld
```